# Javascript Regex: replacing the last dot for a comma

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I have the following code:

```
var x = "100.007"
x = String(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2));
return x
=> 100.01
```

This works awesomely just how I want it to work. I just want a tiny addition, which is something like:

```
var x = "100,007"
x.replace(",", ".")
x.replace
x = String(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2));
x.replace(".", ",")
return x
=> 100,01
```

However, this code will replace the first occurrence of the ",", where I want to catch the last one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
x = x.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ".$1");
```

That regular expression matches a comma followed by any amount of text not including a comma. The replacement string is just a period followed by whatever it was that came after the original last comma. Other commas preceding it in the string won't be affected.

Now, if you're really converting numbers formatted in "European style" (for lack of a better term), you're also going to need to worry about the "." characters in places where a "U.S. style" number would have commas.  I think you would probably just want to get rid of them:

```
x = x.replace(/\./g, '');
```

When you use the ".replace()" function on a string, you should understand that it *returns* the modified string. It does not modify the *original* string, however, so a statement like:

```
x.replace(/something/, "something else");
```

has no effect on the value of "x".

Comment: Be sure to get rid of your period characters BEFORE converting your comma to one or you'll end up with a radically different number! There must be a regex out there that converts periods only if they are followed by a comma and converts the comma only if it is preceded by periods... Think I've just found what I'm doing with my lunch hour...

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using the [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) function to find the last occurrence of the `,` and replace it.

The alternative is to use a regular expression with the end of line marker:

```
myOldString.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ".$1");
```

Comment: Does that work? The first ',' will have an end of line somewhere after it too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regexp. You want to replace the last ',', so the basic idea is to replace the ',' for which there's no ',' after.

```
x.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ".$1");
```

Will return what you want :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lastIndexOf` to find the last occurence of `,`. Then you can use `slice` to put the part before and after the `,` together with a `.` inbetween.

Comment: Wouldn't a regex be better, as it is a pattern match that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about whether or not it's the last ".", because there is only one. JavaScript doesn't store numbers internally with comma or dot-delimited sets.

Comment: Rule number one is to never trust input. So I do worry :) Never the less thank you for your answer.

Comment: Input doesn't matter — you're running `replace` on the output of `String(parseFloat(n).toFixed(2))`, which will always return a string representation of either `nil` or a number with a single decimal and zero commas. JavaScript will NEVER convert a number into a string with comma delimiters unless you write a method to do that specifically.